# What is the different between list1.append(list2) and list1.append(list2[:]) in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

Here are two pieces of similar codes:

```
s='abc'
ans,res=[],[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    ans.append(i)
    res.append(ans[:])
print(res,"\n")
```

Result: [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]

```
ans,res=[],[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    ans.append(i)
    res.append(ans)
print("\n",res)
```

Result: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]

I am confused about the difference between the two results. Why do `res.append(ans)` and `res.append(ans[:])` lead to different return value?

Could anyone give me some hints or tell me any underlying logic that I ignored?

Answer (score 0):

```
s='abc'
ans,res=[],[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    ans.append(i)
    res.append(ans[:])
print(res,"\n")
```

This appends `ans` as the next item of list. If you see how `ans` and `res` change every iteration, you will understand how its is working.
Changes:

```
Iteration-0                   
ans- [0]
res- [[0]]

Iteration-1
ans- [0, 1]
res- [[0], [0, 1]]

Iteration-2
ans- [0, 1, 2]
res- [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

And for the other one:

```
ans,res=[],[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    ans.append(i)
    res.append(ans)
print("\n",res)
```

This overwrites the complete list every iteration like:

```
Iteration-0
ans- [0]
res- [[0]]
Iteration-1
ans- [0, 1]
res- [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
Iteration-2
ans- [0, 1, 2]
res- [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```